# Docusign API: Adding an Empty Textbox

Tags: php, textbox, docusignapi

I am using the Docusign API to populate envelopes from our website (user pays for our service and it fills in the envelope with their info and sends it). I am able to add fields to the envelope with static text using the code below, but how do I add an empty textbox to a specific coordinate? That is, on the first line, how do I make $s2 display an empty textbox instead of a static/uneditable value? Is there a separate array for textboxes instead of textTabs?

```
$s2 = array(
    'documentId' => '3',
    'pageNumber' => '2',
    'xPosition' => '275',
    'yPosition' => '94',
    'value' => substr($first_name, 0, -2),
);
array_push($textTabs, $s2);

$recipients[] = array(
    'roleName' => $client,
    'email' => $email,
    'name' => $name,
    'tabs' => array('textTabs' => $textTabs, 'initialHereTabs' => $initials, 'checkboxTabs' => $checkboxes),
);

etc.
```

Comment: Not clear what is the issue. Textbox and text tab are the same. You want it to have more lines? is that the issue?

Comment: No, right now the text shows up not in a textbox but just the text itself. I need to make it an empty textbox that forces them to fill it in.

Comment: If I send the above code with an empty value nothing shows up.

Comment: Do you have a document with ID "3" that has 2 pages?

Comment: oh wait, this is using a template? that's probably the problem

Comment: Are you sure the roleName matches what's on the template?

Comment: Try to do this with a regular envelope first, to confirm you can get it working correct

Comment: Like I said, i can get everything working fine, like adding checkboxes, signatures, text, etc... but how do I add an empty textbox?

Comment: The connection isn't the problem, I have a working app. But I need to add an empty textbox is all.

Comment: Your code is correct for empty text box

Comment: Weird. I think I need to include show=>true and the height and width.

Comment: Is there a way to set the textbox to a specific recipient?

Answer (score 0):

Only thing missing in here is the **recipientId** and **locked** which should be false by default.
This code works, just tried it:

```
$s2 = array(
    'documentId' => '3',
    'pageNumber' => '2',
    'xPosition' => '275',
    'yPosition' => '94',
    'locked' => 'false',
    'recipientId' => '1'
);
```

Comment: Awesome thank you, I got it working. I also had to add height and width otherwise it was tiny. Are the recipientId's sequential starting at 1?

Comment: That depends, if you set them yourself - you can set any value you want. If it's done by DocuSign, they usually have 7 digit random number (not unique) that is set by the web app

Comment: okay thanks, I found where I was setting that and can use it.